# Tikz Regression Line With Orthogonal Residuals

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I pick the example of drawing a Regression Line from [TikZ: Regression Line with Residuals](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147383/tikz-regression-line-with-residuals).

But now, instead of drawing vertical error bars, i wanted them to be orthogonal to the regression line.
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: But the slope of the regression line assumes the error is in the Y axis. If not the line itself would be placed differently, and you would need assumptions about the relative error to be minimised in each axis (? equal)

Comment: ah sure! I wanted visualize the difference between ordinary linear regression and orthogonal regression, where in fact the line itself would look different. Do you know how to realize that?