# Drawing line from point to automatically fitted linear regression

Tags: tikz-pgf, automation

Hi I have the following code which produces the regression
straight based on the points on the table. I suppose the
red dots on the curve are the equivalent of each point but
on the fitted straight. I would like a way to change the
squares to circles and draw a line from each point the the
square (that will be a circle) automatically if possible.
Thank you very much in advance.
Any advice on how to do better post will also be much appreciated.

```
\pgfplotstableread{
    X Y
    1 1
    2 3
    2.5 3.1
    1.5 2.7
    1.4 1.8
    2 4
    1.2 2
    1.8 2
    2.1 2 
    2.4 2
     
}{\datatable}
\begin{figure}
\label{Linear regression plot}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xlabel={X},
        ylabel={Y},
        legend cell align=left,
        legend pos=north west]
        \addplot[only marks] table {\datatable};
        \addlegendentry{Points $\{x,y\}$ in our dataset}
        \addplot table [y={create col/linear regression={y=Y}}]
        {\datatable};
        \addlegendentry{Fitted simple regression}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Plot of a linear regression}
\end{figure}
```

Output I would like, mine is the same but without the vertical straight lines:

[image: Output I would like, mine is the same but without the vertical straight lines]

Comment: See if https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147383/tikz-regression-line-with-residuals helps.

Comment: Yes it helps, sorry for the repeated question, did not manage to find it. Do I have to delete the post now?

Comment: No worries :) You don't have to delete your post.